# while read loop

Tags: shell-script, scripting, ksh

I have a file like one below

```
var     3   2014   string
var1    4   2011   string4
var2    6   1999   string2
var3    1   2016   string6
```

Then i have this while read loop to compare one of the columns to a number then echo something. However, instead of echoing my desired phrase, it echoes something else.

```
while read num
do
if [ "$num" = "0" ]; then
echo "Number is equal to zero"
else
echo "number is not equal to 0"
fi
done < home/dir/file.txt | awk '{print $2}'
```

instead of echoing the above, it echoes the 2nd column of the file.

Comment: I can't actually reproduce the problem when running the script as-is, but in any case you have other problems with your script. Mainly, you do `read num` and expect the result to be a single number (which you compare against the string "0"), but you are actually reading an input file with 4 columns so `$num` will be a string with 4 columns in it.

Comment: Not tested, but I think your problem is that the pipe will be done after the while loop? Anyway, why not all in awk: `awk '{if ($2==0){print "equal"}else{print "not"}}' file.txt` ?

Comment: As presented, that code snippet would print the second word from each line produced by the `while` ... `done` loop. I.e.: `is` x4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you should try

```
awk '{print $2}' home/dir/file.txt | while read num
do
  if [ "$num" = "0" ]; then
    echo "Number is equal to zero"
  else
    echo "number is not equal to 0"
  fi
 done
```

for a mixed awk/bash solution.

As other have pointed out, awk redirection occur later.

Answer (score 6):

Since I can't comment, just wondering, why people have not used IFS

```bash
while IFS=" " read var num year string
do
  if [[ $num -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Number is equal to zero"
  else
    echo "number is not equal to 0"
  fi
done < home/dir/file.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're trying to redirect the output of `home/dir/file.txt | awk '{print $2}'` to the `while` loop;

first I guess that the correct path should be `/home/dir/file.txt` (however this is just an assumption);

second `/home/dir/file.txt | awk '{print $2}'` doesn't redirect the content of `/home/dir/file.txt` to `awk`, while `< /home/dir/file.txt awk '{print $2}'` does;

third, you're redirecting the output of the command as a file, but it's a string, and you should redirect it as it: `<<< "$(< /home/dir/file.txt awk '{print $2}')"`.

Also, alternatively, you could pipe the output of the command directly to the `while` loop instead: `< /home/dir/file.txt awk '{print $2}' | while read num`.

```bsh
while read num
do
    if [ "$num" = "0" ]; then
    echo "Number is equal to zero"
else
    echo "number is not equal to 0"
fi
done <<< "$(< /home/dir/file.txt awk '{print $2}')"
```

or

```bsh
< /home/dir/file.txt awk '{print $2}' | while read num
do
    if [ "$num" = "0" ]; then
    echo "Number is equal to zero"
else
    echo "number is not equal to 0"
fi
done
```