# Return value from nmap IP address only and pass it into a loop in Bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I have this script of nmap which retrieves only alive IP devices from the network.

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24 | awk '/is up/ {print up}; {gsub (/\(|\)/,""); up = $NF}'
```

I want to get the result IP addresses from nmap to loop through the below command, as far as I understand multiple results may not be having any return value from nmap.

```
echo "# This script checks if a remote device is alive"
read va * This is suppose to receive the IP address one by one
echo "Checking Device "$va
if [ $(nc -z "$va" 22; echo $?) -eq 0 ]; then
echo $va" is Online !"
else
echo "Cannot proceed with remote connection device "$va" is Offline !"
fi
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [while read loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208911/while-read-loop)

Answer (score 2):

You can check for opened tcp port 22 with nmap also.

```
nmap -p 22 192.168.1.0/24 -oG - | grep -oP "Host: \K[^ ]+(?=.* 22/open/tcp.*)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to unix.stackexchange !

`xargs` is your friend here.

But first some changes to your script:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "# This script checks if a remote device is alive"
va=$1 # passing it as an argument is the right thing to do here
echo "Checking Device "$va
if [ $(nc -z "$va" 22; echo $?) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $va" is Online !"
else
    echo "Cannot proceed with remote connection device "$va" is Offline !"
fi
```

And now the `xargs` magic (`%` will be replaced by each address at each call) :

```
$ nmap -sP 172.20.10.1-2 | awk '/is up/ {print up}; {gsub (/\(|\)/,""); up = $NF}' |xargs -I % bash test.sh %
# This script checks if a remote device is alive
Checking Device 172.20.10.1
Cannot proceed with remote connection device 172.20.10.1 is Offline !
# This script checks if a remote device is alive
Checking Device 172.20.10.2
Connection to 172.20.10.2 port 22 [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
172.20.10.2 is Online !
```

You can also replace `bash test.sh %` with `echo ">>>%<<<"` in order to experiment what happens then.

However, Ipor Sircer answer is shorter to implement.

But as always with Unix: there are plenty of solutions for every problem

Comment: Hi all, appreciate the help, will check how to fit it into my scenario..

Comment: ssh root@$var 'df -h; free -m' < /dev/null > > > > > Hi, so the above code with this line results in data received from the remote host, now I want to save this data to a txt file, how can I do that..

Comment: Open a new question to ask this. Comments should be used only to clarify information, not for new topics (hence they have limited formating features). *And do not forget to mark the solution of your question*