# bash loop through file - lines with 2 parameters

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a file that looks like logfiles.txt :

```
log1 ads.log
log2 bdfds.log
log4 cdrfs.log
```

I want to loop through the file:

```
for each lines do:
    echo $logname ;
    clear $logfilename; 
done
```

I know how to do the actions, but how do I loop inside the line for each parameter .

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [while read loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208911/while-read-loop)

Comment: this can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash

Comment: What do you mean with `clear $logfilename`?

Comment: clear is function I use -

Comment: I need to use the line like in an array : 

echo  line [1] ; 
echo line [2];

Comment: Then please edit your question so that _all_ necessary information is readily available for contributors.

Answer (score 1):

Basically

```
while IFS=" " read -r logname logfile
do
    if [[ ! -z $logfile ]]
    then
        echo "$logname"
        clear "$logfile"
    fi
done < logfiles.txt
```

- The `IFS=" "` statement sets the field separator to whitespace, so the tokens are interpreted as space-separated.
- The `if` part guards against empty lines (which seem to be present, looking at your sample input) and those missing the second field.

Comment: I think it's about what I look for, 
and for this to itterate through all lines ? 
a simple for on the file ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I correctly understand your question, but this will read all lines of `logfiles.txt`, extract the two strings, and perform the actions you mentioned in the question. If you are new to shell scripting, may I recommend looking at [GreyCat and Lhunath's Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and using [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) for debugging your scripts.